# Python Paste and auto-restart on non Python source file change

Tags: python, automation, paster

[`paster serve`](http://pythonpaste.org/script/#running-the-server) has `--reload` option to auto-restart serving wsgi application when any of Python source files or the `CONFIG_FILE` changes.
How to make *paster* initiate auto-restart also when some other file (not Python source file) changes?

UPDATE

[`watch_file()`](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/paste/src/160f4747e53ccbc8ed5e474e7a2c589fc21199e3/paste/reloader.py#cl-31) function suggested by *mksh* looks like the solution to the problem. However *mksh* suggested adding its invocation to the application's entry point which seems to be more invasive than it should. Can I (non-intrusively) extend Paste's `serve` command adding new option which would result in invocation of `watch_file()` with filenames read from the app's section in `CONFIG_FILE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Paster source link](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/paste/src/160f4747e53ccbc8ed5e474e7a2c589fc21199e3/paste/reloader.py#cl-31)

So, you can watch your non-source files as simple as putting such lines at bottom of your application`s entry points:

```
from paste.reloader import watch_file

#
# logic that puts list of your non-source file names suitable 
# for open() into iterable non_source_file_list
#

for non_source_file in non_source_file_list:
    watch_file(non_source_file_name)
```

In general, try to rely more on source code than documentation when working with such modern and really written in pythonic style frameworks as Paste, their code is mostly well documented and futhermore self-documenting .

Comment: As I couldn't find any info on this subject on the web I started to dig into source myself and found this function, too. Great find!